# Pid file for mysql on Oneiric

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysql5, ubuntu-11.10

I cannot locate pid file for mysql server on oneiric. Opened /etc/mysql/my.cnf and /etc/mysql/debian.cnf but see no settings about pid file. I need this pid file to have monit monitor mysql.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the pid file is /var/lib/mysql/NODE_NAME.pid, damn it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `/var/run` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do: updatedb; locate mysqld.pid

As root. This should show you where the file is.